# External Geodaya syntax issue

Tags: angular, amcharts

i have a problem while directing geodata for creating a custom map with amcharts, app crashed while says import should be like this = import map=geodataSource.url ; "../../../node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4-geodata/json/primeraseccion.json"; but thats not the way de docs says so (map.geodataSource.url = "/path/to/myCustomMap.json";)

// Importing geodata (map data)
import map=geodataSource.url ; "../../../node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4-geodata/json/primeraseccion.json";

src/app/grafico/grafico.component.ts(15,11): error TS1005: '=' expected.
src/app/grafico/grafico.component.ts(15,30): error TS1005: ';' expected.

Comment: Could you provide a code sample on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/) or [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/)? The `url` should map to an url, but if you're building amCharts with tools, there's no "primeraseccion.json" in the [amcharts4-geodata package](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4-geodata/tree/master/dist/script/json). I'm guessing your node_modules wouldn't be uploaded either, so you'd have to use your json file in a way it would be part of your build/package and still accessible online/as an url. You may need to refer to your bundler's/build tool's documentation.